# Workday SOAP client Unsupported endpoint address

Tags: web-services, soap, workday-api

I am trying to connect to workday HR Web Service. But I am getting:

> WebServiceException : Unsupported endpoint address: Human_Resources.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HumanResourcesService hrservice=new HumanResourcesService();
    HumanResourcesPort hrport=hrservice.getHumanResources();
    //further code
}
```

WebEndpoint Snippet from the HumanResourcesService class:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "Human_Resources")
public HumanResourcesPort getHumanResources() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("urn:com.workday/bsvc/Human_Resources", "Human_Resources"),
            HumanResourcesPort.class);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When defining Workday API endpoints, you need to include the version number at the end of the urn.

For example you have:

```
urn:com.workday/bsvc/Human_Resources
```

and it should be (if you use v28)

```
urn:com.workday/bsvc/Human_Resources/v28.0
```